# Lentidão na resposta (PHP MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, script

```
<?php

require('DB.class.php');


//$conexao = mysql_connect('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx','base_dados','utilizador');

//$db      = mysql_select_db('base_dados',$conexao);


$SQl_list = DB::getConn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `wpr3_posts` WHERE post_content LIKE '%perfil.mercadolivre.com.br/MARCH+GOLD%'");

$SQl_update = DB::getConn()->prepare("UPDATE `wpr3_posts` SET  `post_content` = ? WHERE ID = ?");

$SQl_list -> execute();

var_dump( DB::getConn());

while ($res = $SQl_list->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $h    = str_replace('https://perfil.mercadolivre.com.br/MARCH+GOLD', 'http://perfil.mercadolivre.com.br/MARCH+GOLD', $res['post_content']);

    $SQl_update -> execute(array($h,$res['ID']));
}
```

Este código não é meu, o problema é que com essa codificação o site em geral ficou lento, gostaria de saber qual é o problema e como posso arrumá-lo.
Me disseram que o problema também é que ele substituiu imagens a mais que não eram pra ser substituídas, provavelmente ele puxou imagens a mais do que deveria e agora para carregar o banco de dados, ficou complicado.
Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Qual a quantidades de registros na tabela?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, essa tecnologia está obsoleta desde a versão 5 do PHP e foi removida com a versão 7.
Recomendo o uso da biblioteca mysqli ou PDO para conexão com o banco de dados usando o PHP.

Comment: Aparentemente ele está usando PDO de forma indireta através das classe `DB`. Perceba que as funções obsoletas estão comentadas no código e, por isso, não estão sendo utilizadas de fato.

Answer (score 0):

Uma das formas de melhorar o acesso é ao invés de usar `SELECT *` é colocar o nome dos campos. Revise as tecnologias obsoletas, elas também atrasam o código. Revise o arquivo `DB.class.php` para ver como está sendo feita a conexão.